# Access Azure VM from behind a NAT

Tags: azure, ssh, nat, ssh-tunnel

So I am pretty new to all of this and currently learning about ssh and NAT.

So I have a VM setup on Azure and in order to connect to it I need to ssh into it. But the problem is I am unable to ssh into it because I am behind a NAT as I am currently studying in a University, hence getting "connection timed out" error all the time.

Also I have tried changing the default port(22) to 443 or 80 still same error which confirms I am behind a NAT.

So currently the only way to ssh is to use a VPN which works fine.
But after researching a bit I found that I can also use Reverse SSH Tunneling to achieve the same but couldn't figured out a way of how to do it. I know it is a bit riskier than using a VPN only but anyway just wanted to try.

So can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

An outgoing SSH connection (your machine -> Azure VM) should not be affected if you are behind a NAT. NAT usually blocks incoming SSH access to your machine not out from it.

> Also I have tried changing the default port(22) to 443 or 80 still the same error which confirms I am behind a NAT.

You changed the default port on which machine, you or the Azure VM? Changing the default port on your machine will not affect the outgoing SSH connection as it is only for incoming SSH connection to the SSH server on your machine (if you have one running locally).

Your best bet would be to actually look at the security groups of the Azure Virtual Network you VM is located in. Make sure it allows incoming SSH connection on port 22 to your VM.